# installing specific gdal version with conda fails

Tags: conda, gdal

I try to install a specific gdal version (2.1.4). I use a workflow that I used often before and now it suddenly does not work anymore:

I use the terminal to do:

```
MINICONDANAME=Miniconda2-4.3.30-Linux-x86_64.sh
wget -q http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/$MINICONDANAME -O Miniconda2.sh
bash Miniconda2.sh -b
conda create --name test
source activate test
conda install -c conda-forge gdal=2.1.3

python

>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/geo/home/d067913/envs/miniconda2/envs/eoservice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "/geo/home/d067913/envs/miniconda2/envs/eoservice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/geo/home/d067913/envs/miniconda2/envs/eoservice/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```